# How to select multiple column in PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created a table **messages** that have column **user_id, message_sender, message_receiver, message_receiver_id**

The result of query as below

Line 1 : **2 abol Alang 3**

Line 2 : **2 abol mak 4**

Line 3 : **3 alang abol 2**

Line 4 : **3 alang mak  4**

I want to display the all query that has **Alang** records which is Line 1,3,4. i managed to display line 3,4 only but cannot display line 1. here's the code

```
<?php
    include("includes/connections.php");
    function displaymessagesprofile(){
        global $connect;
        global $user_id;

            $get_id      = $_GET['message_receiver_id'];
            $sql_message = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id='$user_id' OR message_receiver_id='$get_id'";
            $get_message = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_message);

            if($get_message && mysqli_num_rows($get_message) > 0 ){
                while($row_message = mysqli_fetch_array($get_message)){

                $user_id            = $row_message['user_id'];
                $message_sender     = $row_message['message_sender'];
                $message_receiver   = $row_message['message_receiver'];
                $message_receiver_id= $row_message['message_receiver_id'];

                        //to display message sent and received by the user logged in
                        echo    "<div id='message_wrap'>
                                    <p>$message_sender</p>
                                    <p>$message_receiver</p>
                                    <p>$message_receiver_id</p>
                                </div>
                                ";
                }
            mysqli_free_result($get_message);
            }
            else{
                echo "No message yet";
            }
    }
?>
```

errors shows below :

> Notice: Undefined index: message_receiver_id

Comment: You sure you got `message_receiver_id` variable in your URL?

Comment: yeah . sure. undefined index . i dont know why

Comment: in line $get_id      = $_GET['message_receiver_id'];

Comment: Post the code that calls the code you posted.

Comment: What does the URL look like? (You can remove the domain if you'd like) Just want to make sure it's being called correctly.

Comment: the data already in database like above . i just want to display the records .

Comment: Post the URL that redirects to that page.

Comment: it's in local connections

Comment: Do you understand what we are asking? Post the URL or if you don't know it then post the code that redirects you to the specific code you've posted.

Comment: it's ok . i already found the solution. thanks btw . have a good day :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$get_id      = $_GET['message_receiver_id'];

change to

$get_id      = isset($_REQUEST['message_receiver_id']) ? $_REQUEST['message_receiver_id'] : '';
```

You may need to use filter_var disinfection

Comment: errors gone . but the $get_id still didn't show in the result.

Comment: Remember to disinfect, the most basic method is filter_var